# PHP/Apache2 Production web permissions and ownership

Tags: php, apache, unix, webserver

I was always curious what is the best practice for production web pages ran by Apache2 and PHP of folder ownerships and permissions.

Lets say `/srv/www/my-web` is a public folder accessed via http.

How the ownership and permissions should be set to be as restrictive as possible?

My example would be:

```
drwxr-xr-x my-user:www-data /srv/www/my-web
-rw-r--r-- my-user:www-data /srv/www/my-web/index.php    

drwxrwxr-x my-user:www-data /srv/www/my-web/cache
-rw-rw-r-- my-user:www-data /srv/www/my-web/auto-generated-file.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically:

```
Folders: 755 or rwxr-xr-x
Files: 644 or rw-r--r--

find /[webroot] -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; //set all directories to 755
find /[webroot] -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; // set all files to 644
```

Comment: And what about ownership and writing permissions for web user where needed?

Comment: Ownership is impossible to define so easily due to varying server configs, etc. Typically, username:username should be fine for static websites in a typical Linux environement. Example: chown -R username:username /www

Comment: So my example is wrong? If i need write access for web-server-user than i should give 0777 for specific directories and 0666 for specific files. Is that safe?

Comment: I updated my answer above. You should never set permission as 777 as this gives complete access to the file/dir. 666 as well adds additional write permission that are not needed in most cases. Again, 755 and 644 is very typical for your dir/file permission that remains safe.